# illegal hardware instruction (core dumped) crash when NPM on 18.04

Tags: nodejs, npm

I haven't used node/npm in weeks but today so I have no idea since when this is failing. I'm using nodejs `v13.10.1` and npm `v6.13.7` and when I try to install npm dependencies I get the error:

```
[1]    5035 illegal hardware instruction (core dumped)
```

To reproduce I simply do:

```
$ mkdir myAwesomeFolder
$ npm init -y
$ npm typescript
> BUM!
```

Is it possible that the npm is requiring an instruction not supported by my CPU? how is that possible? Can it be an issue with a kernel update? I haven't touched anything.

Any idea of how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `net-keepalive`. Modules like it needs to be compiled for each specific architecture. The module worked when I used node 8 and 10, but when upgraded to 14, my app started crashing

```
#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Check failed: result.second.
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0x7ffed3b1da80
 1: 0x55ad9a832af3  [/usr/bin/node]
 2: 0x55ad9b277038 V8_Fatal(char const*, ...) [/usr/bin/node]
 3: 0x55ad9ac0bd14 v8::internal::GlobalBackingStoreRegistry::Register(std::shared_ptr<v8::internal::BackingStore>) [/usr/bin/node]
 4: 0x55ad9a979582 v8::ArrayBuffer::GetBackingStore() [/usr/bin/node]
 5: 0x55ad9a774406 napi_get_typedarray_info [/usr/bin/node]
 6: 0x7fe23f8cae38 FFI::FFI::InitializeBindings(Napi::Env, Napi::Object) [/myapp/node_modules/net-keepalive/node_modules/ffi-napi/build/Release/ffi_bindings.node]
 7: 0x7fe23f8cb6c0  [/myapp/node_modules/net-keepalive/node_modules/ffi-napi/build/Release/ffi_bindings.node]
 8: 0x7fe23f8c7bb5 __napi_Init(napi_env__*, napi_value__*) [/myapp/node_modules/net-keepalive/node_modules/ffi-napi/build/Release/ffi_bindings.node]
 9: 0x55ad9a7890d4 napi_module_register_by_symbol(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Context>, napi_value__* (*)(napi_env__*, napi_value__*)) [/usr/bin/node]
10: 0x55ad9a78d4b6  [/usr/bin/node]
11: 0x55ad9a78c75a node::binding::DLOpen(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [/usr/bin/node]
12: 0x55ad9a9aae07 v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(v8::internal::CallHandlerInfo) [/usr/bin/node]
13: 0x55ad9a9ab1ce  [/usr/bin/node]
14: 0x55ad9a9aba1a  [/usr/bin/node]
15: 0x55ad9a9ac376 v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/bin/node]
16: 0x55ad9b1463f9  [/usr/bin/node]
[1]    2623 illegal hardware instruction (core dumped)
```

So I updated the module to the latest version, and it works now.

Have you tried to clear the cache?

```
npm cache clear --force
```